# how to know the value of flipToggle from another page using react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new with react native , i have to pages which are homeScreen and profileScreen ,in profile screen there is a flipToggle and in the homeScreen there is a function that will excute if the flipToggle is on (i will use if statement) my question is when i am in homeScreen how to know if the flipToggle is turned on or off using react native

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably using React Navigation, so you can pass params to a route when you navigate to it, example:

```
navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', { 
  flipToggle: yourFlipToggleVariable // true or false
})
```

And in your HomeScreen you can retrieve this params using `navigation.getParam`, example:

```
// The second parameter is a default value    
navigation.getParam('flipToggle', false)
```

But if you want to watch the flipToggle variable i recommend you to search about state mamagement with redux or context (React.createContext)

Some useful links:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#navigate

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

https://redux.js.org/basics/example/